# Getting Email list of people who respond to an email thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I need to get a list of the emails of the people who respond to an email. How would I do this with google apps script? I can't find any seemingly helpful methods under documentation for GmailThread object but that is probably my inexperience with this language

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Comment: [`GmailThread.getMessages()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getMessages()) & [`GmailMessage.getFrom()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getFrom())...?

Comment: [Gmail.search()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String))